# JS: Re-insert array

Tags: javascript

So I have this array:

```
[Object, Object]
  [0]: Object
    ['date']: "2013-12"
    ['views']: 21023
  [1]: Object
    ['date']: "2014-01"
    ['views']: 21312
    length: 2
```

How can I make it

```
 [Object, Object]
   ['date']: Object
      [0]: "2013-12"
      [1]: "2014-01"
   ['views']: Object
      [0]: 21023
      [1]: 21312
```

Apparently this code doesn't work:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
                newArray['date'][i] = oldArray[i]['date'];
                newArray['views'][i] = oldArray[i]['views'];
            };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure you want to create an array like this?

Answer (score 1):

You expected result is not an array, should just be an object.

```
var result = { date: [], views: [] };
for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    result['date'].push(oldArray[i]['date']);
    result['views'].push(oldArray[i]['views']);
};
```